# Using random key/value from YAML file

Tags: ruby, random, yaml, key-value

I'm trying to use a random key, value pair from a YAML file that looks like this:

```
'user_agents':
  'Mozilla': '5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)'
  'Mozilla': '5.0 (compatible; Yahoo! Slurp; http://help.yahoo.com/help/us/ysearch/slurp)'
  'Mozilla': '5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/528.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile/7A341 Safari/528.16'
  'Mozilla': '4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
```

Using this script:

```
require 'mechanize'
require 'yaml'

info = YAML.load_file('test-rand.yml')
@user_agent = info['user_agents'][info.keys.sample]

agent = Mechanize.new
agent.user_agent = @user_agent
if @user_agent.nil?
  puts "The user agent is nil"
else
  puts "Using: #{@user_agent}"
end
```

However while running this script I keep getting the `The user agent is nil`, how do you pull a random key/value from a YAML file?

I've also tried `@user_agent = info['user_agents'][info[rand(values.size)]]`

Comment: yaml translate to the hash and hash in the ruby can contain only unique keys, so you actually have only the last key always   `'Mozilla': '4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)'`.

Comment: Is there a way to go around that?

Comment: use the unique keys in the yaml file.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, is there a way to go around that, like giving a key multiple values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured out a solution for this, if anyone has a better one please let me know, I changed the YAML file to only have one `Mozilla` with multiple values:

YAML:

```
'user_agents':
  'Mozilla': ['5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)', '4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)', '5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/528.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile/7A341 Safari/528.16', '5.0 (compatible; Yahoo! Slurp; http://help.yahoo.com/help/us/ysearch/slurp)']
```

I then took the keys and value and broke down the YAML file into a key value pair using this:

```
info = YAML.load_file('test-rand.yml')
info['user_agents'].each do |k,v|
```

From there I turned the value into an array, sampled the array, and saved the result into a variable, I then created a new hash called `@user_agent` and gave it the key of `k` and the value of `arr_val.to_s`:

```
arr_val = v.to_a.sample
@user_agent = {k => arr_val.to_s}
```

Full script:

```
require 'mechanize'
require 'yaml'

info = YAML.load_file('test-rand.yml')
info['user_agents'].each do |k,v|
  arr_val = v.to_a.sample
  @user_agent = {k => arr_val.to_s}
end

agent = Mechanize.new
agent.user_agent = @user_agent
if @user_agent.nil?
  puts "The user agent is nil"
else
  puts "Using: #{@user_agent}"
end
#<= Using: {"Mozilla"=>"5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/528.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile/7A341 Safari/528.16"}
#<= Using: {"Mozilla"=>"5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"}
#<= Using: {"Mozilla"=>"4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)"}
```

Comment: That's what I was going to suggest. But you can also use dashes instead of `[]` to avoid too long strings: http://pastebin.com/H6BAb8wE

Comment: Huh, I had no idea you could do that! Awesome thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> How do you pull a random key/value from a YAML file?

Your current yaml file contain the same keys `Mozilla`. 
The ruby convert yaml file to the hash. In the ruby hash can contain only unique keys. So your yaml file looks like:

```
=> {"user_agents"=>{"Mozilla"=>"4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)"}}
```

The yml file with the unique keys:

```
'user_agents':
  'Mozilla_1': '5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)'
  'Mozilla_2': '5.0 (compatible; Yahoo! Slurp; http://help.yahoo.com/help/us/ysearch/slurp)'
  'Mozilla_3': '5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/528.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile/7A341 Safari/528.16'
  'Mozilla_4': '4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
```

The Rails console:

```
=> info = YAML.load_file('y.yml')
=> {"user_agents"=>
  {"Mozilla_1"=>"5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)",
   "Mozilla_2"=>"5.0 (compatible; Yahoo! Slurp; http://help.yahoo.com/help/us/ysearch/slurp)",
   "Mozilla_3"=>"5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/528.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile/7A341 Safari/528.16",
   "Mozilla_4"=>"4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)"}}
```

Get the random **value** not the key:

```
=> info["user_agents"]["Mozilla_#{rand(1..4)}"]
#> "5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
=>  info["user_agents"]["Mozilla_#{rand(1..4)}"]
#> "5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/528.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile/7A341 Safari/528.16"
=> info["user_agents"]["Mozilla_#{rand(1..4)}"]
#> "5.0 (compatible; Yahoo! Slurp; http://help.yahoo.com/help/us/ysearch/slurp)"
=> and so on....
```

Comment: You can't add to user agents, or it makes them obsolete. These are _REAL_ user agents, and I'm trying to use them.

Comment: I can't get what you mean.

Comment: A user agent is what is sent from your computer when you go to a website to tell that site where you're coming from. These user agents are real agents, meaning they're used all the time. If you add to the user agent, it's no longer the same agent, and probably doesn't exist.

Comment: The question is __How do you pull a random key/value from a YAML file?__ I post the answer to the question.

Comment: Hey, what if you have multiple different keys?